# Is it possible to combine formatters of Tabulator.info?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using custom formatters like shown here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/format#format-custom

I wonder if it is somehow possible to combine several formatters to one? This would be great in many situations, eg:

```
formatter: function(cell) {
   return getFormatter('bold', cell) + getFormatter('euro', cell);
}
```

Please let me know if that is already possible, thx.

Comment: Why don't you just create your own custom formatter?

Comment: @dota2pro Because that would mean I have to create a custom formatter for every single situation that might come up in the future... Let's say I have these formatters: bold, italic, center, euro, date; What if I want a cell bold+italic+euro and another bold+date --> that would mean I have to build a custom formatter "bold-italic-euro". What if I want to change all formattings of euro --> I have now two formatters where I have duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/format#format-custom) to achieve this.

Formatters can manipulate a lot more than just the contents of a cell so it would not be safe to provide a mechanism for combining them

Comment: Thx Oli, as I said I know about custom formatters. I'm building a plugin for the ProcessWire CMS using tabulator and I came up with this solution:

1) register formatters for the "grid" (that's holding the tabulator instance) - in other words store callbacks in an array
2) use those callbacks, so you can combine formatters

Comment: example:
    grid.addFormatter('bold', function(val, cell) {
      $(cell.getElement()).addClass('uk-text-bold');
      return val;
    });
    grid.addFormatter('danger', function(val, cell) {
      $(cell.getElement()).addClass('uk-text-danger');
      return val;
    });
    grid.addFormatter('bold-danger', function(val, cell) {
      val = grid.getFormatter('bold').apply(val, cell);
      val = grid.getFormatter('danger').apply(val, cell);
      return val;
    });

Comment: Sorry, no idea why code formatting doesn't work :(

https://i.imgur.com/RWSm9lF.png

Comment: If you just want to add classes then u can use the cssClass property in the column definition. Then Tabulator will add it to the cell for you

Comment: Thx, but that's just simple examples. I want to render cells differently based on their value, of course, like so: https://i.imgur.com/AEeo8Pp.png ; My workaround works fine and I think it would be an improvement. The concept is just that formatters always take the cell VALUE and the cell object and return the cell VALUE. Then you can "chain" those formatters as you like and break your code in more logical parts (formatter for currency, formatter for different colors etc)

Comment: Hey @Bernhard, only simple formatters return the cell value. other more complicated ones use the cell component passed into the formatter and use it to manipulate the cell / column / row that the cell is in. There are also callbacks called on the content (some of which can be complex HTML  and JavaScript with event bindings).  Therefore you cannot sensibly chain them in a way that would work for all usage cases for the table. (im the chap that wrote Tabulator so please trust me on this) you are of course free to tweak it to fit your usage case.

Comment: Of course I know who you are ;) I'll stick with my solution then :) Thx for your answers (and for the great library of course).